# is it possible to use imagemin-cli and keep the same folder structure of compressing files?

Tags: npm-scripts, imagemin

I'm trying to create `imagemin` script with npm scripts and using `imagemin-cli` for it. First, I copy files to `dist` (or `.tmp` for development) folder and then compress images with this scripts:

**package.json**

```json
...
scripts {
  "copy:dev": "cpx app/src/**/*.{html,png,jpg,mp4,webm} .tmp/",
  "copy:prod": "cpx app/src/**/*.{html,png,jpg,mp4,webm} dist/",
  "imagemin:dev": "imagemin app/src/images/**/* -o .tmp/images/",
  "imagemin:prod": "imagemin  app/src/images/**/* -o dist/images/",
  ...
},
```

So, when I run these scripts, after compression all images are put inside the folder `images/`.

Is there a way to compress  images and keep the folder structure? Maybe with another plugin or something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it a way to compress images with keeping folder structure?

**The short answer is no, not with `imagemin-cli`**

[imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin), *(the API [imagemin-cli](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-cli) is built upon)*, does not provide a mechanism to preserve the folder structure. See *open* issue/feature-request  [#191](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/issues/191) in the projects github repo.

---

#### Solution

A cross platform way to achieve your requirements is to write a custom *node.js* utility script that utilizes the [imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin) API directly. So effectively... build your own CLI tool that can be run via `npm-scripts`.

The following gists show how this can be achieved...

---

**imagemin.js**

The utility *node* script is as follows:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var readline = require('readline');
var Imagemin = require('imagemin');

var outdir = process.env.PWD; // Default output folder.
var verbose = false; // Default no logging.

// The folder name specified MUST exist in the `glob` pattern of the npm-script.
var DEST_SUBROOT_FOLDER = 'images';

// Nice ticks for logging aren't supported via cmd.exe
var ticksymbol = process.env.npm_config_shell.indexOf('bash') !== -1 ? '✔' : '√';

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: null,
    terminal: false
});

// Handle the optional `-o` argument for the destination folder.
if (process.argv.indexOf('-o') !== -1) {
    outdir = process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('-o') + 1];
}

// Handle the optional `-v` argument for verbose logging.
if (process.argv.indexOf('-v') !== -1) {
    verbose = true;
}

/**
 * Utilizes the Imagemin API to create a new instance for optimizing each image.
 * @param {String} srcpath - The filepath of the source image to optimize.
 * @param {String} destpath - The destination path to save the resultant file.
 * @param {Function} - The relevent `use` plugin (jpegtran|optipng|gifsicle).
 */
function imagemin(srcpath, destpath, plugin) {
    var im = new Imagemin()
        .src(srcpath)
        .dest(destpath)
        .use(plugin);

    im.optimize(function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ' + err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        if (file && verbose) {
            console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', ticksymbol, destpath);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Obtains the destination path and file suffix from the original source path.
 * @param {String} srcpath - The filepath for the image to optimize.
 * @return {{dest: String, type: String}} dest path and ext (.jpg|.png|.gif).
 */
function getPathInfo(srcpath) {
    var ext = path.extname(srcpath),
        parts = srcpath.split(path.sep),
        subpath = parts.slice(parts.indexOf(DEST_SUBROOT_FOLDER), parts.length);

    subpath.unshift(outdir);

    return {
        dest: path.normalize(subpath.join(path.sep)),
        ext: ext
    };
}

/**
 * Triggers the relevent imagemin process according to file suffix (jpg|png|gif).
 * @param {String} srcpath - The filepath of the image to optimize.
 */
function optimizeImage(srcpath) {
    var p = getPathInfo(srcpath);

    switch (p.ext) {
    case '.jpg':
        imagemin(srcpath, p.dest, Imagemin.jpegtran({ progressive: true }));
        break;
    case '.png':
        imagemin(srcpath, p.dest, Imagemin.optipng({ optimizationLevel: 5 }));
        break;
    case '.gif':
        imagemin(srcpath, p.dest, Imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: true }));
        break;
    }
}

// Read each line from process.stdin (i.e. the filepath)
rl.on('line', function(srcpath) {
    optimizeImage(srcpath);
});
```

***Note:*** *The code above uses version `1.0.5` of the `imagemin` API and not the latest version - Why? See point 1 under the Additional Notes section below.)*

---

**Uninstall and Install new packages**

1. Firstly uninstall `imagemin-cli` as it's no longer necessary:

`$ npm un -D imagemin-cli`

2. Next install [imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin) version **`1.0.5`** *(This is an older package so may take `npm` longer to install than usual)*

`$ npm i -D imagemin@1.0.5`

3. Then install [cli-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-glob). This will be used to specify the glob pattern to match the images for optimizing.

`$ npm i -D cli-glob`

---

**npm-scripts**

Update your `npm-scripts` as follows:

```js
...
"scripts": {
    "imagemin:prod": "glob \"app/src/images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}\" | node bin/imagemin -v -o dist",
    "imagemin:dev": "glob \"app/src/images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}\" | node bin/imagemin -v -o .tmp",
    ...
},
...
```

***Note:*** *To optimize images using the gists shown above it's not necessary to use the two scripts named `copy:prod` and `copy:dev` shown in your original post/question)*

1. The `glob \"app/src/...` part of the script above uses [cli-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-glob) to match the necessary image source files.
2. The paths are then piped to the `imagemin.js` utility node script.
3. When the `-v` (verbose) argument/flag is included then each processed image is logged to the console. To omit logging simply remove the `-v` flag.
4. The `-o` (output) argument/flag is used to specify the destination folder name. E.g. `dist` or `.tmp`. When the value for `-o` is omitted the resultant images are output to the project root directory.

---

**Additional notes:**

1. The reason for using `imagemin` version [1.0.5](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/tree/v1.0.5#usage) is because this API
   allows the `src` value to be specified as a single filepath. In versions greater than `2.0.0` the API expects the `src` value to be a glob pattern as shown in the latest version [5.2.2](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/tree/v5.2.2#usage).
2. The gists above assume `imagemin.js` is saved to a folder named `bin` which exists in the same folder as `package.json`. It can be changed to a preferred name, or an invisible folder by prefixing it with a dot [.] e.g. `.scripts` or `.bin`. Whatever you choose, you'll need to update the path to the script in `npm-scripts` accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

## Update 2020

**There's an unmerged (as of mid-june 2020) [pull request](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/pull/353) by Gijs Rogé that enables preserving directory structure in the output directory.**

You can install npm modules not yet listed in the registry by installing directly from Github, referencing a repo and even specific commit:
`npm install https://github.com/<username>/<repository>#<commit> --save-dev`

To install imagemin with Gijs Rogé’s fix, run...
`npm install https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin#bfd7c547045f68ed92243c6a772f6265a08a687f --save-dev`

...and enable the new option in your script by setting `preserveDirectories: true`:

```
// Note: imports and plugin configs have been omitted for brevity

const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');
...

(async () => {
    const files = await imagemin(['input_dir/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg}'], {
    destination: 'output_dir/',
    ✨preserveDirectories: true,
        plugins: [
            imageminMozjpeg( ... ),
            imageminPngquant( ... ),
            imageminSvgo( ... )
        ]
});
```

A `.jpg` found in `input_dir/some/sub/dir/image.jpg` will now be processed and written to `output_dir/input_dir/some/sub/dir/image.jpg`.

Use `destination: '.'` to overwrite original files in place.

Answer (score 0):

i had also the same problem but i changes the index.js file of imagemin in node modules. please copy paste the code in node modules

```js
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const fileType = require('file-type');
const globby = require('globby');
const makeDir = require('make-dir');
const pify = require('pify');
const pPipe = require('p-pipe');
const replaceExt = require('replace-ext');

const fsP = pify(fs);

const handleFile = (input, output, options) => fsP.readFile(input).then(data => {
 const dest = output ? output : null;

 if (options.plugins && !Array.isArray(options.plugins)) {
  throw new TypeError('The `plugins` option should be an `Array`');
 }

 const pipe = options.plugins.length > 0 ? pPipe(options.plugins)(data) : Promise.resolve(data);

 return pipe
  .then(buffer => {
   const ret = {
    data: buffer,
    path: (fileType(buffer) && fileType(buffer).ext === 'webp') ? replaceExt(dest, '.webp') : dest
   };

   if (!dest) {
    return ret;
   }

   return fsP.writeFile(ret.path, ret.data)
    .then(() => ret)
    .then(function(result) {})
  })
  .catch(error => {
   error.message = `Error in file: ${input}\n\n${error.message}`;
   throw error;
  });
});

module.exports = (input, output, options) => {
 if (!Array.isArray(input)) {
  return Promise.reject(new TypeError(`Expected an \`Array\`, got \`${typeof input}\``));
 }

 if (typeof output === 'object') {
  options = output;
  output = null;
 }

 options = Object.assign({plugins: []}, options);
 options.plugins = options.use || options.plugins;

 return globby(input, {onlyFiles: true}).then(paths => Promise.all(paths.map(x => handleFile(x, output, options))));
};

module.exports.buffer = (input, options) => {
 if (!Buffer.isBuffer(input)) {
  return Promise.reject(new TypeError(`Expected a \`Buffer\`, got \`${typeof input}\``));
 }

 options = Object.assign({plugins: []}, options);
 options.plugins = options.use || options.plugins;

 if (options.plugins.length === 0) {
  return Promise.resolve(input);
 }

 return pPipe(options.plugins)(input);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script runs a separate `imagemin` job for each folder.

It solves the same problem.

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const imageminWebp = require('imagemin-webp');

const COMPRESSED_FOLDER = '__compressed';
const TIMER_NAME = 'compressed';

(async () => {
  console.time(TIMER_NAME);
  const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public');
  const compressedFolderRegExp = new RegExp(COMPRESSED_FOLDER);
  const publicPathRegExp = new RegExp(publicPath);
  const folders = getAllDirectories(publicPath).filter(
    (directoryName) => !directoryName.match(compressedFolderRegExp)
  );

  await Promise.all(
    folders.map(async (folderPath) => {
      const destination = folderPath.replace(
        publicPathRegExp,
        `${publicPath}/${COMPRESSED_FOLDER}`
      );

      console.log('compressing...', destination);

      return imagemin([`${folderPath}/*.{jpg,png}`], {
        destination,
        plugins: [imageminWebp({ quality: 50 })],
      });
    })
  );

  console.timeEnd(TIMER_NAME);

  process.exit();
})();

function getAllDirectories(filepath) {
  const directoryPaths = fs
    .readdirSync(filepath, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter((d) => d.isDirectory())
    .map(({ name }) => `${filepath}/${name}`);
  const childDirectories = directoryPaths.reduce(
    (acc, directoryPath) => acc.concat(getAllDirectories(directoryPath)),
    []
  );

  return [filepath, ...childDirectories];
}
```